# Pandas groupby drop index when groupby object is storred

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

When one stores the `groupby` object before calling `apply`, the index is dropped somewhere. How can this happen?

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'b': list(range(4))})
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x)
   a  b
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  2
3  0  3
dfg = df.groupby('a')
dfg.apply(lambda x: x)
   b
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

## EDIT:

I was on pandas 0.23.2 but this bus is not reproducible with pandas 0.24.x. So upgrading is a solution.

Comment: For me working correct in pandas 0.24.2 - output is same

Comment: cant reproduce, both gives me same output.

Comment: ok I'm pandas 0.23.2 they must have fixed this bug then. I shall close the question, thanks!

Comment: still I am surprised this can happen because from a python point of view it seems like it should be exactly the same